# Get all Matches in regular expression between delimiters that might appear multiple times

Tags: regex, multiple-matches

I have this sample data:

```
101 ASDFSDAFFA FASDFF TR QWETYUK K PPOWERETY                                                       Lpqeor:  #
    QEREYERP ASJDFL;Z                                                                              PUTO_LJL;_QWERUOIUO
    --                                                                                             QERT
    --                                                                                             ASPOU3OIUW  QW
    --                                                                                             NMBMSJQOET
    --
    OOPPWERPOQETUIOPYPOIUQEW
2  EWPROIWEURQPWEOIRUQWPEORIUQWEPORIJASDFKLJQPOWIERUAJASKLDFJQPWEOIRUQWPEIORUQWPEROIQWUEPROQIWEURQWPEORIUWPQEOIRUASA;K
   QWERPQWOEIURQPWOEIRUPQWOEIRUQWPEORIQWUF;AKLSJDFPQIWEURS;KLADFJPQOWIEURAS;LDKFJQPOWIERUAS;DFKLAJS;DLKFQWEPRIOQUWEPOI 
3
101 ASDFSDAFFA FASDFF TR QWETYUK K PPOWERETY                                                       Lpqeor:  #
    QEREYERP ASJDFL;Z                                                                              PUTO_LJL;_QWERUOIUO
    --                                                                                             QERT
    --                                                                                             ASPO3POIUW  QW
    --                                                                                             NMBMSJQOET
    --
    OOPPWERPOQETUIOPYPOIUQEW
2  EWPROIWEURQPWEOIRUQWPEORIUQWEPORIJASDFKLJQPOWIERUAJASKLDFJQPWEOIRUQWPEIORUQWPEROIQWUEPROQIWEURQWPEORIUWPQEOIRUASA;K
   QWERPQWOEIURQPWOEIRUPQWOEIRUQWPEORIQWUF;AKLSJDFPQIWEURS;KLADFJPQOWIEURAS;LDKFJQPOWIERUAS;DFKLAJS;DLKFQWEPRIOQUWEPOI 
3
```

And I want to use a regular expression to capture everything between 101, and the lonely 3, that's also the start of a line, so far, I managed to find this expression:

```
^1(?s)(.*?)3
```

But it stops after it finds the first 3 between the characters, and I want it to capture everything until it gets to the 3, and that might repeat several times, in the example, the pattern appears only twice, but there could be a thousand instances of this pattern.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/xd1ou0/1)

Comment: does `^101([\s\S]*?)^3$` do what you want? Please provide a sample input and desired output.

Comment: Don't use a regex, read your file by line and use a simple test to know when the line starts with 101 or 3.

Comment: @ConCave it doesn't match anything, what I want to do is use that expression to read a file in Java, an only read the parts that match that Regular Expression using a Stream.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I thought it would be just quicker to use a regular expression. I first thought about doing it that way, and then thought that maybe it would mean that I'm a bad programmer because I should be using a Regular Expression for doing that. Maybe it'll be quicker if I go with your suggestion :/ but I wanted to try something new.

Comment: @AnubisLockward: it's a totally wrong idea.

Comment: Try `(?m)^101(?:.*\s+)*?^3.*`

Comment: @sln thanks a lot..worked like a charm